# Different transition for each transform

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve to have different transition for each transform when class is added/removed from element. Best solution would be not modifying HTML structure or even adding additional classes.

```
.navbar {
    height: 60px;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    transition: transform .5s ease; /* for transform: translate(0, -60px); */
    transition: transform .2s linear; /* for transform: translate(200px, 0); */
}

.navbar.slide-up {
    transform: translate(0, -60px);
}

.navbar.slide-left {
    transform: translate(200px, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add the transition on the togglable classes

```
.navbar {
    height: 60px;
    transition: transform .35s;   /* same for both when class is removed  */
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.navbar.slide-up {
    transition: transform .5s ease; /* for transform: translate(0, -60px); */
    transform: translate(0, -60px);
}

.navbar.slide-left {
    transition: transform .2s linear; /* for transform: translate(200px, 0); */
    transform: translate(200px, 0);
}
```

---

Updated, 2:nd

*Note, based on how your script looks like, it might be possible to use the given transition and set it to the `navbar` on removal using `cssText` (and if, you won't need the extra classes)*

---

Updated

If it will be possible to add 2 more classes, one can get a unique transition when resetting the elements position

With this, you first clear all classes, add one of them, and then, on removal add its reverse.

```
.navbar {
    height: 60px;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.navbar.slide-up {
    transition: transform .5s ease; /* for transform: translate(0, -60px); */
    transform: translate(0, -60px);
}

.navbar.slide-left {
    transition: transform .2s linear; /* for transform: translate(200px, 0); */
    transform: translate(200px, 0);
}

.navbar.slide-up-reverse {
    transition: transform .5s ease; /* for transform: translate(0, -60px); */
}

.navbar.slide-left-reverse {
    transition: transform .2s linear; /* for transform: translate(200px, 0); */
}
```

Comment: This will not perform animation in both directions. When for example class slide-up is added animation will be performed correctly, but when this same class is removed, there'll be no animation.

Comment: @izupet Updated my answer. For the reverse (when class is removed) animation, there can only be one, unless you add an extra class for each removal transition.

Comment: @izupet Based on how your script looks like, it might be possible to use the given transition and set it to the `nav` on removal, and with that you won't need the extra classes ... post the script if you want me to have a look at how to do that